# Surface integral finding the $u$ and $v$ vectors

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

While calculating a surface integral, how do you know which variable to use as $u$ and $v$ in the calculation?

For example in Cartesian coordinates you have $x$, $y$ and $z$.

In cylindrical $\theta$, $r$ and $z$.

And in polar $\theta$, $\rho$ and $\phi$.

I’m confused as to which two should you choose as $u$ and $v$ to work out the question as I end up with different answers.

Comment: You use the variables of the parametrization. So for instance, if you were to integrate over the upper hemisphere of the unit sphere, you could parametrize it as $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and compute everything w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, or you could parametrize it as $(\theta,\phi) \mapsto (\cos\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta \cos\phi, \sin\phi)$, and compute w.r.t. $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: why not w.r.t. y and z? why would you choose x and y?

Comment: You can name them whatever you like. $(☺, ☹)\mapsto (☺, ☹, \sqrt{☺^2+ ☹^2})$ works equally well. That being said, there are certain conventions which you can obey (but don't have to, however it is recommended that you do, in order not to confuse yourself and everyone else).

Comment: Is it that you look at the variables that parametrize the "shadow" of the surface on an axis?

Comment: Not necessarily. In the first parametrization $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$, the variables can be thought of as "shadows", but in general this gets more complicated, as the second parametrization $(\theta, \phi) \mapsto (\cos\theta, \cos\phi, \sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\phi)$ shows.

Comment: Does it matter which variables are used then? After looking at examples my lecturer did there are two examples done in cylindrical coordinates where he used θ and r in one and θ  and z in the other, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Again, the names of the variables are irrelevant. However, it is important to know how those variables are connected to your parametrization. There are certain conventions, such as using $x,y,z$ when working in Cartesian coordinates, and using $r,\theta, \phi$ in polar coordinates, but is just a matter of convenience, and is irrelevant for the computations behind it.

Comment: You misunderstand what I mean, I'm not speaking about the names, when you parametrize why would you use x and y and not y and z? why would you use r and θ not θ and ϕ? What are the conditions for choosing these TWO variables to do the calculation?

Comment: You choose the most convenient one. For instance, if $x^2+y^2$ appears somewhere in the definition of your surface, it usually indicates that polar/cyllindric coordinates are the way to go. If $x^2+y^2+z^2$ appears then spherical coordinates usually work wonders. But that's very specific to the situation, and impossible to know in general.

Comment: example 1 on this website is an example of what i have trouble understanding, why did he do the question w.r.t y and z?
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx

Comment: In that particular case, there is no reason to choose one over the other. It would have been equally as easy to work w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, or $x$ and $z$. However, coming back to the example of the upper hemisphere of the unit sphere, it is much easier to work w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, than, say, $y$ and $z$, since if you were to work w.r.t. $y$ and $z$, you would have to split your integral into two parts. So again, this is very specific to the situation. Sketching the surface usually helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time Sobi

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if the discussion helped!